# Resource not found when view is open for editing in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I find the behaviour I describe below somewhat intermittent and unpredictable, but is there anything I can do to avoid it completely?

If I have a view open in a code editor window in VS, regardless if a save is pending or not, when I try and navigate to that view in my browser, I get a "resource not found" (to that effect at least), until I close the editor, then I can normally navigate to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you mean by *navigate to a view*. In ASP.NET MVC you cannot navigate to a view. You navigate to controller actions which render the corresponding view. If you try to drectly access a view in the `~/Views` folder the access will be denied. To avoid having Visual Studio always run the current file in the browser you could set a specific page to run in the properties of the project:

[image]

Comment: When I talk about navigating to a view, it is from a user perspective.  The view is what I see in the browser when I click a link, clicking that link is navigating to the view.